# What is the most efficient way to check if data that the client app send is from the same tenant in multi-tenant app?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi tenant app with ASP Web API + Entity Framework + Angular. The api will be published to public, so i have to make sure that no 3rd party app can mess with the data.
I have a sales entity that has customer navigation property. when client app create new sales and send it to the server, how do i check on the server that customer entity assigned to the sales entity are from the same tenant? I was thinking that before updating entity, i will fetch related customer data from database and check the tenant id. But i'm afraid it will impact the performance badly, especially with entities that has a lot of navigational properties. Any better solution or idea?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

**Customer Entity:**

Id

TenantId

Name

**Sales Entity:**

Id

TenantId

Date

CustomerId --> how do i make sure this customerid is from the same tenant

Amount

Comment: Do you use a separate database for each tenant?

Comment: If you are happy to violate the fact that a restful service should be stateless, then you can store the correct tenant id in session and you can then compare the request without fetching from the database.

Comment: @Magrangs I used one shared database for all tenants

Comment: @Ben Robinson  I cannot do that. That means if one tenant has 1000 customers, than i have to put all of them to session

Comment: @Reynaldi Ok, I use a different database for each tenant and then have a TenantManger database which holds the details of the tenant databases. Associated to each tenant is an ApiKey. I send this in the headers of the request. From that I can inject the correct database instance into the controller and just perform selects as normal and as I am operating on the correct database instance I don't encounter these issues. Might be worth considering something like that?

Comment: @Magrangs Yes, that is one of the advantages to have 1 database for each tenant. But my team and i are not considering to move to single database per tenant (yet) :)

Comment: What happens if a tenant messes up and requests a restore from backup?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pulling something out of the database by ID would impact performance. You should really profile this case. If you really don't want to pull the data from the database you can always make the database do it and add a before insert trigger or do everything in a stored procedure.

Also note that your database is not normalized. Maybe there are good reasons for this but theoretically you don't need TenantId in your Sales table. If you accept that the sales entity TenantId is the Customer's TenantId then all is fine.

Comment: I haven't profile this before, but i will soon. My sample is simple with only 1 relation. Imagine a table with 10-20 relations. So it would make 20 calls to the database before actually saving it. I guess it will pretty much impact the performance, especially if the database is not in the same server like in azure.

Comment: I have tenant id in sales table to make querying easier. I even have tenant id in almost all tables. So when i want to query all sales, i dont always have to join customer table.

Comment: Well OK then we fallback to my Trigger or SP suggestion.

Comment: I really like ORMs but I have always thought that they should be use for trivial cases. The moment you start wondering about something complex you can downgrade to a SP. There is a reason all ORMs support SPs and we should not shy from using them.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Magrangs comment, I would suggest to use an ApiKey to be pased in the http header.

You would store in a table the relation between a tenant id and the ApIKey. This way, you can easily find out in which tenant you should store the records.

I would even suggest that your service / business layer should take care of setting the tenant id. This way you don't have to worry about your client sending the wrong tenant id.

This is the approach we use in our system and it streamlines the management of the tenant context.

Comment: And this solution hides the multi-tenant concept to the third app using your API who don't need to know anything about it

Comment: yes i'm using api key and the client app would not know about the tenant. in my case, the clientapp will only supply customerid. my question is what is the fastest and most efficient solution to check whether the customer id belong to the same tenant.

Comment: i think the title of my question is misleading. i will change it.

Comment: If this is your only question, you can certainly check this in your SQL statement (yes wrapping all this in SPs is better anyway) Depending on the usage, you could also cache the tenant of your customer records to perform the check on the API side.